# How to verify an inequality?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, inequalities

I'm working with an expression that seems to be non-positive, but I'm having a hard time verifying it:

```
f1[λ_, 
  n_] := (1/
    64) (-64 - (8 λ (-4 + 
         2 r + λ + (-2 + r) r λ + 
         2 λ^2 + λ^3) ((-2 + r)^4 + (2 - r)^
          n (1 + λ)^(
          4 - n)) (5 + (-4 + r) r + λ (2 + λ)))/((-2 +
          r)^4 r (1 + λ)^3 (-1 + ((2 - r)/(1 + λ))^
         n)) + 64 (1 - ((-1 + λ)^2 (((2 - r)/(1 + λ))^
            n + (-2 + r)^2/(1 + λ)^2))/((-2 + 
            r) r (-1 + ((2 - r)/(1 + λ))^
            n))) (1 + ((-1 + λ) (1 + λ) (((2 - 
                r)/(1 + λ))^
            n + (-2 + r)^2/(1 + λ)^2))/((-2 + 
            r) r (-1 + ((2 - r)/(1 + λ))^n))) + (4 (-1 + 
         r + λ) (-4 + 
         2 r + λ + (-2 + r) r λ + 
         2 λ^2 + λ^3) (1 + (-2 + 
            r)^2/(1 + λ)^2) (-(-2 + r)^(2 n) (1 + λ)^(
          8 - 2 n) (-20 + 
            2 r (13 + (-6 + r) r) + λ + (-2 + 
               r) r λ + 2 λ^2 + λ^3) + (-2 + 
            r)^7 (10 + 2 (-4 + r) r + 6 λ + 
            r (5 + (-4 + r) r) λ + 
            2 (4 + r) λ^2 + (6 + r) λ^3 + 
            2 λ^4) + (2 - r)^(2 + n) (1 + λ)^(
          2 - n) ((-2 + 
              r)^4 - (1 + λ)^4) (-(-4 + n) (-2 + 
               r)^2 λ - (-4 + 
               n) λ (1 + λ)^2 - 
            2 (-2 + r) (1 + λ) (-3 + n + λ))))/((2 - 
         r)^7 (1 + λ)^3 (3 - r + λ) (r - 
         r ((2 - r)/(1 + λ))^n)^2) + 
    4 (-4 λ + (2 (1 + λ) (2 + ((-2 + r) (-4 - 
                 2 r (-1 + λ) + r^2 λ + 
                 3 λ (1 + λ)^2))/(1 + λ)^3 + \
((2 - r)/(1 + λ))^(-3 + 
              n) (-λ - ((-2 + r) (10 + 
                    2 (-4 + r) r + (-2 + 3 r) λ + (-4 + 
                    3 r) λ^2))/(1 + λ)^3)))/(r - 
          r ((2 - r)/(1 + λ))^
           n)) (2 + ((-2 + r)^4 (1 + λ)^
           n (-1 + r + λ) (8 + 
             2 (-3 + r) r + (-1 + 
                r (5 + (-3 + r) r)) λ + (-5 + 
                r^2) λ^2 + (-3 + 
                r) λ^3 + λ^4) + (2 - r)^

           n (1 + λ)^3 (4 r^5 λ + 
             r^4 (4 + (-27 + λ) λ) + 
             2 r^3 (-13 + λ (33 + λ + 
                   3 λ^2)) + 
             2 r^2 (32 + λ (-27 + λ (-9 + (-13 + \
λ) λ))) + (-1 + λ) (1 + λ) (-28 + \
λ (-37 + λ (-1 + λ + λ^2))) + 
             2 r (-1 + λ) (35 + λ (46 + λ (28 \
+ λ (2 + λ))))))/(2 (-2 + 
            r)^4 r (1 + λ)^3 ((2 - r)^n - (1 + λ)^
            n))))
f2[λ_, n_] := 
 f1[λ, n] /. r -> Sqrt[4 - (1 + λ)^2]

Plot3D[f2[λ, n], {λ, 0, 1}, {n, 7, 500}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50]
```

I'm trying the following, but the code is running for many hours, but with no solution or error, nothing:

```
True === FullSimplify[f2[λ, n] <= 0, 
  Assumptions -> 
   n ∈ Integers && n > 7 && λ ∈ Reals && 
    0 < λ <  1]
```

which may be indicative that I'm following the wrong route. So, I'd like to ask: what is the proper way to verify the inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

`f1` is

```
f1[λ_, 
   n_] := (1/
     64) (-64 - (8 λ (-4 + 2 r + λ + (-2 + r) r λ + 
          2 λ^2 + λ^3) ((-2 + r)^4 + (2 - r)^
            n (1 + λ)^(4 - n)) (5 + (-4 + 
             r) r + λ (2 + λ)))/((-2 + 
           r)^4 r (1 + λ)^3 (-1 + ((2 - r)/(1 + λ))^n)) + 
     64 (1 - ((-1 + λ)^2 (((2 - r)/(1 + λ))^
              n + (-2 + r)^2/(1 + λ)^2))/((-2 + 
             r) r (-1 + ((2 - r)/(1 + λ))^
              n))) (1 + ((-1 + λ) (1 + λ) (((2 - 
                  r)/(1 + λ))^
              n + (-2 + r)^2/(1 + λ)^2))/((-2 + 
             r) r (-1 + ((2 - r)/(1 + λ))^n))) + (4 (-1 + 
          r + λ) (-4 + 2 r + λ + (-2 + r) r λ + 
          2 λ^2 + λ^3) (1 + (-2 + 
              r)^2/(1 + λ)^2) (-(-2 + r)^(2 n) (1 + λ)^(8 - 
              2 n) (-20 + 
             2 r (13 + (-6 + r) r) + λ + (-2 + r) r λ + 
             2 λ^2 + λ^3) + (-2 + r)^7 (10 + 2 (-4 + r) r + 
             6 λ + r (5 + (-4 + r) r) λ + 
             2 (4 + r) λ^2 + (6 + r) λ^3 + 
             2 λ^4) + (2 - r)^(2 + n) (1 + λ)^(2 - 
              n) ((-2 + 
                r)^4 - (1 + λ)^4) (-(-4 + n) (-2 + 
                 r)^2 λ - (-4 + n) λ (1 + λ)^2 - 
             2 (-2 + r) (1 + λ) (-3 + n + λ))))/((2 - 
           r)^7 (1 + λ)^3 (3 - 
          r + λ) (r - r ((2 - r)/(1 + λ))^n)^2) + 
     4 (-4 λ + (2 (1 + λ) (2 + ((-2 + r) (-4 - 
                  2 r (-1 + λ) + r^2 λ + 
                  3 λ (1 + λ)^2))/(1 + λ)^3 + ((2 - 
                   r)/(1 + λ))^(-3 + 
                 n) (-λ - ((-2 + r) (10 + 
                    2 (-4 + r) r + (-2 + 3 r) λ + (-4 + 
                    3 r) λ^2))/(1 + λ)^3)))/(r - 
           r ((2 - r)/(1 + λ))^n)) (2 + ((-2 + r)^4 (1 + λ)^
             n (-1 + r + λ) (8 + 
              2 (-3 + r) r + (-1 + r (5 + (-3 + r) r)) λ + (-5 + 
                 r^2) λ^2 + (-3 + r) λ^3 + λ^4) + (2 -
                r)^n (1 + λ)^3 (4 r^5 λ + 
              r^4 (4 + (-27 + λ) λ) + 
              2 r^3 (-13 + λ (33 + λ + 3 λ^2)) + 
              2 r^2 (32 + λ (-27 + λ (-9 + (-13 + λ) \
λ))) + (-1 + λ) (1 + λ) (-28 + λ (-37 + \
λ (-1 + λ + λ^2))) + 
              2 r (-1 + λ) (35 + λ (46 + λ (28 + \
λ (2 + λ))))))/(2 (-2 + r)^4 r (1 + λ)^3 ((2 - r)^
              n - (1 + λ)^n))));
```

`f2` is

```
f2[λ_, n_] := f1[λ, n] /. r -> Sqrt[4 - (1 + λ)^2]
```

`λ` must be less than `1` since

```
Limit[f2[λ, n], λ -> 1]

{* Indeterminate *)
```

You must restrict `n` to be positive since

```
Assuming[0 <= λ < 1, f2[λ, -1] > 0 // Simplify]

(* True *)
```

Then

```
dom = FunctionDomain[{f2[λ, n], 0 <= λ < 1, 
    n >= 0}, {λ, n}] // 
  FullSimplify[#, {0 <= λ < 1, n >= 0}] &

(* λ < 1 && 
 2 n ∈ Integers && (1 + λ)^
  n != (2 - Sqrt[-(-1 + λ) (3 + λ)])^n && 
 Sqrt[-(-1 + λ) (3 + λ)] (-1 + ((
      2 - Sqrt[-(-1 + λ) (3 + λ)])/(1 + λ))^n) != 0 *)
```

The function is only real when `n` is a half-integer or an integer, e.g.,

```
Cases[Table[{n, f2[1/2, n]} // N, {n, 7, 10, 0.01}], {_, _Real}]

(* {{7., -0.0198283}, {7.5, -0.0205678}, {8., -0.0211701}, {8.5, -0.0216021}, \
{9., -0.0219313}, {9.5, -0.0221699}, {10., -0.0223461}} *)
```

To find a counterexample, i.e., a case for positive value

```
(max = NMaximize[{f2[λ, 15/2], 0 <= λ < 1}, λ,
    WorkingPrecision -> 15]) // InputForm

(* {157.718867374661801065017629336351\
13483888`15., {λ -> 0.999999996825\
62313888743502729994361289`15.}} *)
```

The function will be positive for half-integer values of `n` and values of `λ` sufficiently close to `1`

```
f2[1 - 10^-9, 35/2] // N[#, 20] &

(* 51.603721769605913357 *)
```

Comment: Could you explain to me the appended part // 
  FullSimplify[#, {0 <= λ < 1, n >= 0}] &

Comment: It determines the domain for which `f2` is real. See [`FunctionDomain`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionDomain.html) documentation. When you see a function that you don't understand, highlight it and press `F1` for help.

Comment: I was referring to the appended portion only. When I ran your code, I got a different output on that line (incomplete in comparison to yours).

Comment: Postfix use of `FullSimplify` to simplify the output of `FunctionDomain` using the assumptions `{0 <= λ < 1, n >= 0}`